# CSS flex with one column expanding with its content and one column taking the rest of the available space

Tags: html, css

I want the buttons column to expand with its content and the title column to just take up the remaining space.

I created a layout that does what I want in Chrome browser, but it feels like a hack to set the title column to `flex-grow:9999;` and I suspect it might give unexpected results in some situations.

What would be a more correct way to achieve the same results?

```css
.cont {
  display: flex;
}

.title {
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: lightblue;
  flex-grow: 9999;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.buttons {
  background: pinK;
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
}

.buttons>div {
  background: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.buttons>div:last-child {
  margin-right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="title">
    Title title title title title title title title title title title title title
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <div>btn</div>
    <div>btn</div>
    <div>btn</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try `flex-basis: max-content;` for `.title` instead of `flex-grow: 9999` and add a few buttons to see the ellipsis working. `ellipsis` needs an elements max or width set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the kind of fix you want?

```css
.cont {
  display: flex;
}

.title {
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: lightblue;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.buttons {
  background: pink;
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}

.buttons>div {
  background: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="cont">
  <div class="title">
    Title title title title title title title title title title title title title
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <div>btn</div>
    <div>btn</div>
    <div>btn</div>
  </div>
</div>
```